# Unable to populate data on the dropdown on React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, react-router

I have two schemas on the MongoDB. "Assign schema" which contains two fields user_story_id and user_id and another schema for User_story which contains the description of the user story. I want to create drop down within a form which will populate the assigned user stories. The assigned user story id can be obtained from the Assign schema and the User stories descriptions can be obtained from the User_story schema. So, I need both schemas for the implementation. Basically, we need to create a mapping between "Assign" and "User_story" schema. I implemented it in React. The implementation code block is

The code block is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Task({}) {
  
  const [taskValues, setTaskValues] = useState({
    task: '',
    userStory: 'userStory1', // Default value
    createdBy: 'user1',       // Default value
    status: 'Pending',       // Default value
  });

  const [allTask, setAllTask] = useState([{}]);
  const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([]);
  const[allStories, setAllStories] = useState([{}]);
  


  const assignedUserStories = assigned.map((assigns) => {
    return assigns.user_story_id;
  
  })

  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setTaskValues({ ...taskValues, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')
  const handleCreateTask = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const taskDetails = {
        task: taskValues.task,     //captured from input task
        user_story_id: taskValues.userStory,      //captured from dropdown
        status: taskValues.status,      //captured from status dropdown
        created_by: loggedInUser
    }

    // Post taskValues data to your server endpoint
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/createTask', taskValues)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        alert('Task creation Successful');
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert('Error in creating the task');
    });
  };

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTaskList').then(function (response) {
      const Taskdata = response.data;
      setAllTask(Taskdata);
    });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getUserstory').then(function (response) {
      const Allstories = response.data;
      setAllStories(Allstories);
    });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getAssignedstories').then(function (response) {
      const Allassignedstories = response.data;
      setAllAssign(Allassignedstories);
    });


  }, []);
 
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Task</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Task:</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    name="task"
                    value={taskValues.task}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>User Story:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="userStory"
                    value={taskValues.userStory}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    {assignedUserStories.map((stories) =>
                      <option key={stories._id} value={stories._id}>{stories.user_story}</option>
                    
                    )}
                   
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Created by:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="createdBy"
                    value={taskValues.createdBy}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
                    <option value="user2">User 2</option>
                    <option value="user3">User 3</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Status:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="status"
                    value={taskValues.status}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  >
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Awaiting Confirmation">Awaiting Confirmation</option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                    
                  </select>
                </div>

                      <button
                      onClick={() => handleCreateTask()}
                      className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                      >
                      Assign
                      </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is no error while I run the code but it is unable to populate the drop-down. The get connections are ok.
I can see the list of user stories using http://localhost:9000/getUserstory. The screenshot below [image]

I am also able to see the assigned user stories using http://localhost:9000/getAssignedstories. The screenshot below

[image]

I did not understand why the form unable to generate the drop down. My form looks like

[image]

The user story list is empty.

The User story schema as follows

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserStorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_story: String,
    project_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    priority: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      },
    
});

const Story = mongoose.model("Story", UserStorySchema);

module.exports = Story;
```

The assigned schema as follows

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const AssignedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_story_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

const Assign = mongoose.model("Assign", AssignedSchema);

module.exports = Assign;
```

Comment: Do the mapped `assigns.user_story_id` values in the `assignedUserStories` array have `_id` and `user_story` properties? `assigns.user_story_id` looks like string values.

Comment: I updated my question with schemas structure. User_story is a string. The user_story_id on the "Assigned" schema is a foreign key which refer "User_story" schema. If you follow the /getUserStory url you can see the first entry of the user story details will be assigned as the 1st entry of the url /getAssignedstories. I marked those two ids as well in the pictures.

Comment: In your user stories dropdown you use `stories.user_story`. `stories` being the value in `assignedUserStories` which only contains the `user_story_id`. So it has no `user_story` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code

```
const assignedUserStories = assigned.map((assigns) => {
  return assigns.user_story_id;
})
```

that creates a list of `user_story_id`'s only, should really be a filter on the `allStories` for the items that are matched in the `assigned` list.

so something like

```js
const assignedUserStories = allStories.filter((story) => {
  return assigned.some(({
    user_story_id
  }) => user_story_id === story._id)
});
```

Comment: I modified the code as suggested. But then unable to submit the form. I raised this question on Stackoverflow. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77470478/unable-to-submit-the-form-react-component. Can you please take a look? This is the continuous of the question posted here.