# Unable to submit the form React component

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I created a form in React to input some form values and those values will be saved into a MongoDB database called *tasks*.

My code block is as follows

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Task({}) {

  const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem('loggedInUser')
  const [taskValues, setTaskValues] = useState({
    task: '',
    userStory: ' ', // Default value
    createdBy: loggedInUser,       // Default value
    status: ' ',       // Default value
  });

  const [allTask, setAllTask] = useState([{}]);
  const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([]);
  const[allStories, setAllStories] = useState([{}]);
  


  const assignedUserStories = allStories.filter((story) => {
    return assigned.some(({
      user_story_id
    }) => user_story_id === story._id)
  });

  
  
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTaskValues({ ...taskValues, [name]: value });
   };

  
    // Post taskValues data to your server endpoint
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/createTask', taskValues)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.data) {
        alert('Task creation Successful');
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert('Error in creating the task');
    });
  };

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getTaskList').then(function (response) {
      const Taskdata = response.data;
      setAllTask(Taskdata);
    });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getUserstory').then(function (response) {
      const Allstories = response.data;
      setAllStories(Allstories);
    });

    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getAssignedstories').then(function (response) {
      const Allassignedstories = response.data;
      setAllAssign(Allassignedstories);
    });


  }, []);
 
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

  


  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Task</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Task:</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    name="task"
                    value={taskValues.task}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>User Story:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="userStory"
                    value={taskValues.userStory}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    {assignedUserStories.map((stories) =>
                      <option key={stories._id} value={stories._id}>{stories.user_story}</option>
                    
                    )}
                   
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Created by:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="createdBy"
                    value={taskValues.createdBy}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
                    <option value="user2">User 2</option>
                    <option value="user3">User 3</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Status:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="status"
                    value={taskValues.status}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Awaiting Confirmation">Awaiting Confirmation</option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                    
                  </select>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  Create Task
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

I got the errors like

```
src\components\Task.js
  Line 48:5:    React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 51:7:    'setAllTask' is not defined                                                                                                         
                no-undef
  Line 56:7:    'setAllStories' is not defined                                                                                                      
                no-undef
  Line 61:7:    'setAllAssign' is not defined                                                                                                       
                no-undef
  Line 86:28:   'taskValues' is not defined                                                                                                         
                no-undef
  Line 87:31:   'handleInputChange' is not defined                                                                                                  
                no-undef
  Line 96:28:   'taskValues' is not defined                                                                                                         
                no-undef
  Line 97:31:   'handleInputChange' is not defined                                                                                                  
                no-undef
  Line 99:22:   'assignedUserStories' is not defined                                                                                                
                no-undef
  Line 112:28:  'taskValues' is not defined
```

What I need to modify to run the code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems you've some disconnect between the actual code and whatever you may have running/served to the browser and generating errors. Try killing all dev servers, code watchers, hot reloaders, etc, and restart the app from scratch. Can you [edit] to share how `Task` is being rendered and how you are running the application? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the answer after your comment. Make sure your backend is running properly.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Task({}) {
  const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("loggedInUser");
  const [taskValues, setTaskValues] = useState({
    task: "",
    userStory: " ", // Default value
    createdBy: loggedInUser, // Default value
    status: " ", // Default value
  });

  const [allTask, setAllTask] = useState([{}]);
  const [assigned, setAllAssign] = useState([]);
  const [allStories, setAllStories] = useState([{}]);

  const assignedUserStories = allStories.filter((story) => {
    return assigned.some(({ user_story_id }) => user_story_id === story._id);
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setTaskValues({ ...taskValues, [name]: value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9000/getTaskList").then(function (response) {
      const Taskdata = response.data;
      setAllTask(Taskdata);
    });

    axios.get("http://localhost:9000/getUserstory").then(function (response) {
      const Allstories = response.data;
      setAllStories(Allstories);
    });

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:9000/getAssignedstories")
      .then(function (response) {
        const Allassignedstories = response.data;
        setAllAssign(Allassignedstories);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Post taskValues data to your server endpoint
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:9000/createTask", taskValues)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data) {
          alert("Task creation Successful");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert("Error in creating the task");
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h2 className="card-title">Create a New Task</h2>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Task:</label>
                  <textarea
                    className="form-control"
                    name="task"
                    value={taskValues.task}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>User Story:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="userStory"
                    value={taskValues.userStory}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    {assignedUserStories.map((stories) => (
                      <option key={stories._id} value={stories._id}>
                        {stories.user_story}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Created by:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="createdBy"
                    value={taskValues.createdBy}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    <option value="user1">User 1</option>
                    <option value="user2">User 2</option>
                    <option value="user3">User 3</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Status:</label>
                  <select
                    className="form-control"
                    name="status"
                    value={taskValues.status}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                  >
                    <option value="New">New</option>
                    <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                    <option value="Awaiting Confirmation">
                      Awaiting Confirmation
                    </option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                  Create Task
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, there is a dedicated close reason for issues caused by typos, if this is indeed the issue.

Comment: @chankruze Although, it solved the previous problem but raised a new problem. A window popped up and showed "Error in creating task". I did not put data because of this problem.

Comment: @Encipher You have to update the data posting to backend. Right now it's in the component body that needs to be moved to a function like `onSubmit` or something.

Comment: That I did. There is an error in the frontend. I am able to identify it.